# Which shortcode need for Visual Studio for Mac to get Intellisense to complete an expression like map?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

I have this here: `Object.keys(layoutItems).map`

I would press something when cursor is at the end of `map`, and I would expect to have brackets and a variable in place. Which shortcodes I have to press in Mac in Visual Studio?

I know `Ctrl + space`, but it only show the possible upcoming expressions, but after selecting one, does not puts in as Xcode does in Swift.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you join to new Project from Github which is [Github Copilot](https://copilot.github.com/). after using this amazing tool it can suggest to you best sentences to complete your code.

Comment: promising, but I would stuck to Visual Studio

Comment: Why you don't use it? @János

Comment: I like standard things, ready made in visual Studio or Atom.

Comment: If Apple or Macrosoft integrat it, I will be happy.